# Arc Recyclerview with 360 degree scrolling

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out a way to layout a series of views around a circle. I need to achieve Recycler view scrolling 360 degree I am attaching my current result. but in this code the arc not scrolling as 360 degree and it giving margin between each items. Kindly help me to fix the issue. Your help will be appreciated.

```
  @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        fill(recycler, state); // fill with child views based on the current state & position
    }
    
    private void fill(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (recycler == null || state == null) return;
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler); 
        for(int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++)
        {
            View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(i); 
            addView(view);
            int viewWidth = (int) pxFromDp(context, 60f);
            int viewHeight = (int) pxFromDp(context, 60f);
            float left = (i * viewWidth) - horizontalOffset;
            float right = left + viewWidth;
            Pair<Integer, Double> top = computeYComponent((left + right) / 2, viewHeight);
            float bottom = top.first + viewHeight;
            double alpha = top.second; 
            view.setRotation(((float)(alpha * (180 / Math.PI))) - 85f);
            measureChildWithMargins(view, viewWidth, viewHeight);
            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(view, (int) left, top.first, (int) right, (int) bottom);
        }
        List<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> scrapList = recycler.getScrapList();
        for (RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder : scrapList) {
            recycler.recycleView(viewHolder.itemView);
        }
    }

    // determines how much you need to push an item downwards
    private Pair<Integer, Double> computeYComponent(float viewCenterX, float h /* height */) {
        int screenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        double s = ((double) screenWidth) / 6;
        double radius = (h * h + s * s) / (h * 2); 
        double xScreenFraction = (double) viewCenterX / (double) screenWidth;
        double beta = Math.acos(s / radius); 
        double curvatureFactor = 1.75; 
        double alpha = beta + (curvatureFactor * xScreenFraction * (Math.PI - (0.0 * beta)));
        double yComponent = radius - (radius * Math.sin(alpha)); // vertical component of the position of the circle
        return new Pair<>((int) yComponent, alpha);
    }
    private float pxFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
        return (dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDWS3.png

Expected Result - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TGBb4m98J3_IUZBOTfrE2l8QIasLx8u-/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: the drive link you provided is currently inaccessible.